# Product tax calculation slightly wrong

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, tax, shipping-tax

If I add a product that costs `4.20` (without tax) to the cart 100 times, the tax calculation is wrong: `420*0.08 = 33.6`, but Magento says `420*.08 = 34.00`, as can be seen here:

[image]

I have checked this issue and it seems to affect all products.

Any idea what might lead to this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it does seem like a rounding error.

Fortunately I was able to fix it by changing `System -> Configuration -> Calculation Settings -> Tax Calculation Method Based On` from `Unit Price` to `Row Total`.